# What is the name of this rhyme scheme: ABABCCDDC?

Tags: poetry, rhymes

What is the name of this rhyme scheme:

> A B A B C C D D C

A list of (other) rhyme schemes can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme_scheme).

An example can be found on [this page](http://www.poetrymagnumopus.com/index.php?/topic/1195-found-at-shadow-poetry/).

> *Sweet Destiny* by **Jan Turner** (stanza 1)
>
> Oh destiny, sweet destiny,
>
> Come silent in the night,
>
> And teach my spirit how to see
>
> Within tomorrow's light.
>
> I know I'll strive to do what's best
>
> For humankind's eternal quest. . .
>
> I know I'll strive
>
> I know I'll strive
>
> Oh destiny to meet the test.

Comment: Why do you think it has one? That list seems fairly complete.

Comment: @PeterShor I am not sure that it has a name. It is not a very exotic structure, so maybe it has a name.

Comment: Do you know of some poems that use it?

Comment: @PeterShor An example is **Sweet destiny** by *Jan Turner* on [this page](http://www.poetrymagnumopus.com/index.php?/topic/1195-found-at-shadow-poetry/) where they also say that it is a *Trijan refrain* as more properties than only this specific rhyme scheme are involved.

Comment: Maybe my question is too general.

Comment: Your question should include the reference and example you give in the comment. However, the term 'Trijan refrain' seems to be not widely used and is arguably not in the lexicon.

Comment: Do you have an example of poetry in English in this scheme?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, see the link to **Sweet destiny** by *Jan Turner* in my previous comment.

Comment: *ABABCCDDC* is a good name.

Comment: Can you add a quote from the linked site to the textbook of your question? SE likes self contained questions and answers, and there is linkrot.

Answer (score 10):

This is a Ronsardian Ode and was named after Pierre de Ronsard:

***[Ronsardian Ode](http://poetscollective.org/poetryforms/tag/ababccddc/)***

> The Ronsardian ode (named after Pierre de Ronsard 1524-1585) is the
>   only kind of ode that specifies a particular rhyming scheme –
>   ababccddc, with syllable counts of 10, 4, 10, 4, 10, 10, 4, 4, 8.

(poetscollective.org)

Also cited [here](http://www.poetrymagnumopus.com/index.php?/topic/695-ronsardian-ode/), in a thread on poetrymagnumopus:

> The Ronsardian Ode is the creation of a deaf, French poet Pierre de
>   Ronsard (1524-1585). He was known as the Prince of Poets, a "romance"
>   poet. Ronsard's work is musical, sensuous and pagan. Interesting that
>   he was cleric in minor orders and yet his poems focused more on the
>   beauties and sorrows of his loves than spiritual matters.The structure
>   of this stanzaic form is specific, like the Keatsian Ode it follows a
>   uniform stanzaic pattern. It is its unique pattern that sets it apart.
>
> The elements of the Ronsardian Ode are:
>
> ```
> stanzaic, written in any number of 9 line stanzas.
> syllabic, 10-4-10-4-10-10-4-4-8 syllables per line.
> rhymed, rhyme scheme ababccddc.
> ```

Comment: Nice. Do you have an example of poetry in English in this scheme?

Comment: @Mitch There are examples in the first link I posted. Also an example in the second link. Here is another: 'The Prisoner' - http://randomwriterlythoughts.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/ronsardian-ode.html

Comment: @Mitch: Also a [16th century example](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/45218) by Edmund Spencer. (Scroll down to get to the verses in Ronsardian Ode form.)

Comment: Is it still a Ronsardian Ode if the syllable count is off?

Comment: @davo the syllable count is an integral part of the scheme, a poem with a different syllabic structure wouldn't qualify.

Comment: @Davo: what is probably the first Ronsardian Ode in English (see my comment above) has either four or five syllables in the lines that are supposed be four syllables, and the longer lines are also sometimes off by a syllable or so. So the syllable count needn't be exact, but it should be close.

Comment: I'm not sure whether Pierre Ronsard wrote any "Ronsardian odes''. It looks like the word was first used by C. S. Lewis, who wrote describing Edmund Spencer's poem *Aprill*: *"We begin 
with thirty-six decasyllabics and then have a Ronsardian ode. 
Long and short lines are mixed in a regular pattern ..."* Ronsard wrote a number of French poems where long and short lines were mixed in a regular pattern, and it appears that Ronsard was a major influence of Spencer. But this particular pattern of long and short lines might easily have been Spencer's invention.

Comment: I expect that by "Ronsardian ode" C.S. Lewis just meant that Spencer's ode was inspired by Ronsard, in that it followed a repeated pattern of long and short lines (something Ronsard did in a number of his poems). But then somebody read "Ronsardian ode", looked at Spencer's poem, and took that as the definition. So the first "Ronsardian ode" appeared in 1579, and the second probably sometime well after 1944, when C.S. Lewis described Spencer's poem as a "Ronsardian ode".